# Автокомплит после точки в комментариях Dart VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Я начинаю изучать язык **Dart** и в качестве текстового редактора использую **VS Code**. Когда я пишу комментарий и ставлю точку, то **intellisense** пытается мне подсказать, что нужно ввести, но мне это не нужно. Это очень мешает,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тех, кто возможно столкнется с данной проблемой, смотрите в сторону настройки `editor.quickSuggestions`, для комментариев можно выключить подсказки (автокомплит).